# Adding Transparency/alpha to Embedded Font

Tags: apache-flex

I have embedded a font type in my application. Its working fine inside a text area. Now i need to add 60% transparency to it. In fact I need multiple transparency levels. Like -

1. 60 % transparency for TextARea
2. 70% for WindowShade Header etc.

How do I add alpha values to it?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Adobe's own explanation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Working_with_Text_17.html) of how to do this.